# How can I replace the word 'later' (as in 'two days later')?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

How can I replace the word 'later' (as in 'two days later')? Can I say 'two days on'? Doesn't sound right, but I heard 'on' being used in the meaning "further in time".

Comment: We usually use expressions like _two days later_ in narratives about the past. You could replace it with _after two days_ or _in two days' time_.

Comment: @KateBunting 'Two days on' is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: It's not _wrong_, but it would not be the usual way of expressing the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not "two days on".  You could have "two days later on".

There is no real reason not to use later.  I suppose you could say "two days after that" (where "that" refers to some event previously mentioned)

> The first earthquake was on Monday and one day later smoke was seen rising from the volcano's crater.  Two days after that, a powerful eruption blew out the side of the mountain.

Comment: 'In two days' time' is also fine, no qualifications, is it right? Or is it only applicable when talking about future, not future-in-the-past events?